# MATLAB figure into presentation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to export a plot from MATLAB to keynote presentation, however I don't want to place it as pdf on keynote and I don't want to screenshot with the white background, is there anyway I can take the figure with transparent background?

I am using 2014b MATLAB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab: Save figure with transparent background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134642/matlab-save-figure-with-transparent-background)

Comment: this answer doesn't answer my question

Comment: Why doesn't it answer your question? The mentioned links provide ways to export as `png`,`eps`,`pdf` or `svg` with transparent backgrounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2014b gives you the options to change the Edit>Copy Options... from the figure window.  Selecting this option brings you to the Preferences, where you can select the background color (figure, white, transparent), as well as the format.  Once these are set, you can use Edit>Copy Figure to grab the figure for keynote.

Comment: You might also want to add this information to the possible duplicate I linked, as it has been viewed over 5000 times and may be helpful to others.