# Changing Scatter plot background to Transparent

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a .fig file that contains results from some Monte-Carlo simulation and it looks as following;

[image]

When I try to set the background of the image to be transparent in order to show it in a PowerPoint slide, it turns black.

I try to do it by using

```
1) Tools-> Edit plot-> double clicking on the plot -> color set to none.
2) Tools-> Edit plot-> double clicking on the whole figure -> color set to none (this one changes the screen to black)
```

[image]

Any reason? or is there other way I can make it transparent?

Thank you

Comment: I think its transparent. How can you see if something is transparent? Because you see whatever is behind it. In this case, its likely that whatever is behind it its black. Have you tried to save it and overlay it over something else?

Comment: I tried to copy figure and it copy with black background

Comment: copy how? How are you saving it?

Comment: Edit->Copy figure-> Pasting it in my PowerPoint. When I saved the black image to png it shows with white background..

Comment: Regarthless of the transparency, thats a bad way of copying your figure if you want reliability. In any case, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134642/matlab-save-figure-with-transparent-background . I highly suggest `export_fig`. However note that its an old answer and its deprecated. Since 2014, this should be possible if you save the figures

Comment: That's weird =S, Export_fig did the job tho, thank you mate.